# AIX/KSH Extract string from a comma seperated line

Tags: awk, substring, ksh, delimiter, aix

I want to extract the part **"virtual_eth_adapters"** from the following comma seperated line:

```
lpar_io_pool_ids=none,max_virtual_slots=300,"virtual_serial_adapters=0/server/1/any//any/1,1/server/1/any//any/1","virtual_scsi_adapters=166/client/1/ibm/166/0,266/client/2/ibm/266/0",virtual_eth_adapters=116/0/263,proc_mode=shared,min_proc_units=0.5,desired_proc_units=2.0,max_proc_units=8.0
```

Im using AIX with ksh.

I found a workaround with awk and the -F flag to seperate the string with a delimiter and then printing the item ID. But if the input string changes the id may differ...

Comment: Welcome to SO, yes this could be done in `awk`, on SO we encourage users to post their questions along with their efforts, so request you to add your efforts in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Good that you have added information what you tried, keep it up. We do encourage users to add their code itself, there is nothing right or wrong code in it, since we all are here for learning, so request you to add your effort in form of code in your questions always, cheers.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I'm sorry if the post sounded like a I'mToLazyToUseGoogle guy.. I am a bit deadlocked with awk (see my edit) maybe there is a better solution

Comment: Glad that it helped you, keep sharing and keep learning on this great site SO, cheers and happy Learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following in case you want to print string `virtual_eth_adapters` too in output.

```
awk '
match($0,/virtual_eth_adapters[^,]*/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
virtual_eth_adapters=116/0/263
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to print only value for String `virtual_eth_adapters` then try following.

```
awk '
match($0,/virtual_eth_adapters[^,]*/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+21,RLENGTH-21)
}
' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
116/0/263
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for code.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program here.
match($0,/virtual_eth_adapters[^,]*/){       ##Using match function of awk here, to match from string virtual_eth_adapters till first occurrence of comma(,)
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)            ##Printing sub-string whose starting value is RSTART and till value of RLENGTH, where RSTART and RLENGTH variables will set once a regex found by above line.
}
' Input_file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

I do use these approach to get data out in middle of lines.

```
awk -F'virtual_eth_adapters=' 'NF>1{split($2,a,",");print a[1]}' file
116/0/263
```

Its short and easy to learn. (no counting or regex needed)

- `-F'virtual_eth_adapters='` split the line by `virtual_eth_adapters=`
- `NF>1` if there are more than one field (line contains `virtual_eth_adapters=`)
- `split($2,a,",")` split last part of line in to array `a` separated by `,`
- `print a[1]` print first part of array `a`

Comment: thank you for your solution! is it possible to extend the "search pattern"? So I want to select the attributes 'virtual_eth_adapters' and 'virtual_scsi_adapters'. I tried to extend the "-F Part" with double || or &&. But I don't know if its even possible to have mutliple spilts..

Comment: @Ganisarc If you like both as a field separator this should work:  `-F'virtual_eth_adapters=|virtual_scsi_adapters=' 'som code'`

Answer (score 0):

And one more solution (assuming the position of the string)

```
awk -F\, '{print $7}'
```

If you need only the value try this:

```
awk -F\, '{print $7}'|awk -F\= '{print $2}'
```

Also is possible to get the value on this way:

```
awk -F\, '{split($7,a,"=");print a[2]}'
```

Comment: This will easily fails. If there are more lines, or data change place.  Its also field `#7` and not `#5` OP likes to get.  You do seldom need to use two `awk`.  Do like this: `awk -F\, '{split($7,a,"=");print a[2]}'`  to get last part

Comment: @Jotne, the idea with `split` is good, will add it to the answer. But the script will not fail if you have more lines :)

Comment: It will print field 7 of all lines, not only the one with `virtual_eth_adapters`